# Incomplete umra

Tags: fiqh, sex, umrah

While performing umra my baby continuously cries and me and my hus could not able to complete our umra.Without knowing that we can continue umra if we are in Makkah itself,we had sex.Now we repent that .we are financially so tight that we cant afford cutting a goat.Is there any other solutions for this so that we get our rewards for our umra.

Answer (score 1):

Umra is a religious pilgrimage but does not constitute to the five pillars of Islam. However, if one wants to do it then there is no prohibition either. If you can't afford umra becuase your baby is crying or financial constraints you may go home. God is not going to hold you accountable for things that are beyond your ability to control.

Secondly, Sex in Mekkah is not haram... Infact, our prophet pbuh had his first sexual intercourse in Mekkah...You should not be repenting for fulfilling a sunnah.

Lastly, why would you cut a goat while performing an Umra?, that's animal cruelty and a sin... If by that you mean to perform the ritual of sacrificing a goat, then its perfectly fine if you can't afford it... It doesn't matter. Sacrificing a goat is not obligatory. Even the act of doing Umra is not obligatory. If you cannot afford it you don't have to.